# How to specify a connection string to a dbcontext from the command line

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have a solution containing two projects. one asp.net core and and class lib dotnet.core. I am using the class lib only to run migrations . I would like to be able to switch the connection string from dev to prod when i invoke "dotnet ef database update". Is there a clean way to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tell entity framework exactly what db context to update by passing the "-c" arg if your using the dotnet cli or the --context command in the package manager console.

`dotnet ef database update -c {DbContextName}`

or

`Update-Database --context {DbContextName}`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/migrations

---

If you want to change the connection string based on the environment at run time you can use the

`dotnet run -e|--environment {EnvironmentName}`

Then inside your configure services method inside the Starup.cs method do something like

```
    public IHostingEnvironment hostingEnv;
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        if (hostingEnv.IsEnvironment("{EnvironmentName}"))
        {
            services.AddDbContext<DbContextName>(options =>
                    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DbContextNameFromAppSettings.JsonFile")));
        }
        else
        {
            services.AddDbContext<DbContextName>(options =>
                    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("OtherDbContextNameFromAppSettings.JsonFile")));
        }
    }
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments

Answer (score 1):

As you want to change connection string based on Environment type, you may use `--environment` [option](https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet.html#dotnet-ef-database-update):

```
-e|--environment <environment>  The environment to use. If omitted, "Development" is used.
```

to specify is it Dev or Prod and then override connection string based on this.